# Rad Scheduler Textbox in Advanced form

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am working on `RadScheduler`

```
<telerik:RadScheduler ID="RadScheduler1" runat="server" DataEndField="End" DataKeyField="ID"
        DataRecurrenceField="RecurrenceRule" DataRecurrenceParentKeyField="RecurrenceParentID"
        DataSourceID="SchedulerDataSource" DataDescriptionField="Description" Height="700px"
        DataStartField="Start" DataSubjectField="Subject" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true"
        Skin="Windows7" OnAppointmentCreated="RadScheduler1_AppointmentCreated" AdvancedForm-Enabled="true"
        OnAppointmentDataBound="RadScheduler1_AppointmentDataBound1" OnDataBound="RadScheduler1_DataBound"
        StartInsertingInAdvancedForm="true">
        <AppointmentContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true" />
        <AdvancedForm Modal="true" />
        <TimelineView UserSelectable="false" />
        <ResourceTypes>
            <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="RoomsDataSource" ForeignKeyField="RoomID" KeyField="ID"
                Name="Room" TextField="RoomName" />
            <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="DocDataSource" ForeignKeyField="DoctorID" KeyField="UID"
                Name="DoctorName" TextField="first_name" />
            <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="PatientDataSource" ForeignKeyField="PatientID"
                KeyField="UID" Name="PatientName" TextField="FullName" />
            <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="TypeDataSource" ForeignKeyField="TypeID" KeyField="UID"
                Name="Type" TextField="UtilityValue" />
            <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="SqlClinic" ForeignKeyField="CompanyId" KeyField="CompanyId"
                Name="Clinic" TextField="CompanyName" />
        </ResourceTypes>
        <ResourceStyles>
            <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Text="DoctorName" BackColor="Chocolate" />
        </ResourceStyles>
        <AppointmentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Panel ID="RecurrencePanel" CssClass="rsAptRecurrence" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                <asp:Panel ID="RecurrenceExceptionPanel" CssClass="rsAptRecurrenceException" runat="server"
                    Visible="false" />
                <asp:Panel ID="ReminderPanel" CssClass="rsAptReminder" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                <%#Eval("Subject") %>

            </div>
            <hr />
            <div>
                           Doctor: <strong>
                    <%#Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("DoctorName").Text%>
                </strong>
                <br />
                Patient: <strong>
                    <%#Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("PatientName").Text%>
                </strong>
                <br />
                Room: <strong>
                    <%#Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("Room").Text%>
                </strong>
                <br />
                Type: <strong>
                    <%#Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("Type").Text%>
                </strong>
                <br />
                Clinic : <strong>
                    <%#Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("Clinic").Text%>
                </strong>
                <br />

            </div>
        </AppointmentTemplate>

    </telerik:RadScheduler>
    <telerik:RadToolTipManager ID="RadToolTipManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxUpdate="RadToolTipManager1_AjaxUpdate">
    </telerik:RadToolTipManager>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SchedulerDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DeleteAppointments" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Appointments] ([Subject], [Start], [End], [RecurrenceRule], [RecurrenceParentID], [Description], [RoomID],[DoctorID],[PatientID],[TypeID],[CompanyId]) VALUES (@Subject, @Start, @End, @RecurrenceRule, @RecurrenceParentID, @Description, @RoomID,@DoctorID,@PatientID,@TypeID,@CompanyId) select @@Identity"
        SelectCommand="SearchAppointmentsDefault" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Appointments] SET [Subject] = @Subject, [Start] = @Start, [End] = @End, [RecurrenceRule] = @RecurrenceRule, [RecurrenceParentID] = @RecurrenceParentID, [Description] = @Description, [RoomID] = @RoomID,[DoctorID]=@DoctorID,[PatientID]=@PatientID, [TypeID]=@TypeID,[CompanyId]=@CompanyId WHERE [ID] = @ID">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Subject" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="End" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecurrenceRule" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RecurrenceParentID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RoomID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DoctorID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PatientID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TypeID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CompanyId" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="AuditId" Type="Int64" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadScheduler1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadScheduler1" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RoomsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [RoomName] FROM [Rooms]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DocDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [UID], [first_name] FROM [Teacher]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PatientDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SelectPatients" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TypeDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [UID], [UtilityValue] from [utility] where utilityGroup='Type'">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDoctor" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="GetTeacherInfoForScheduler" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="companyId" Type="string" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlClinic" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="getCompanies" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="string" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


by using this I can able to get the patients names but they are loading in dropdown,
<telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="PatientDataSource" ForeignKeyField="PatientID"
                KeyField="UID" Name="PatientName" TextField="FullName" />
```

There are 4000 patients.  The DropDown does not allow text based searches. Users must scroll through thousands of patients to find the one they are looking for.

Is there a control, such as `autocompletefield`, which better fits my needs?

Comment: You've posted too much of your telerik markup and not enough usable information. just post the snippet that is giving you trouble. Also post some of the final HTML that is rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're already using Telerik, you coul use the [ComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx)

That being said, there are simple ways of doing this with jQuery as well. One of the best I've found is the [SelectToAutocomplete plugin](https://github.com/JamieAppleseed/selectToAutocomplete). It'll take your standard select box and awesomeize it.

Comment: <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="PatientDataSource" ForeignKeyField="PatientID"
                KeyField="UID" Name="PatientName" TextField="FullName" />

Thanks for your reply. I am just using the Resources in Scheduler So i couldn't able use it as a dropdown

Comment: What does your final HTML look like?